# How to format dates in react, and have the rules applied to them like range and starting from minimum range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, date, react-datepicker

I have a react app, the requirement is to have date inputs. One is startDate and another is endDate.
There are some rules,

1. The Start Date can be today or any future date. (So what's happening here is, when users get to the page, they can see the date is already populated and show them the current date and they can change it.)
2. End Date will have the start date as the minimum date.
3. End Date will show date as 12/31/9999. But, if the user wants to change the date, the calendar should open at the minimum value i.e., the selected start date. Navigating from year 9999 to 2023 is not a good experience.

Below is my component (I'm using `<input type='date'/>`, But if it is easier in the react-datepicker library, I can use that)

I need the date format as **mm/dd/yyyy**.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const DateInput: React.FC = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(() => {
    const today = new Date();
    const year = today.getFullYear();
    const month = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    const day = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  });

  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState('9999-12-31');

  const handleStartDateChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const newStartDate = event.target.value;
    setStartDate(newStartDate);

    console.log(`New Start Date: ${newStartDate}`);
    console.log(`Selected End Date: ${endDate}`);
  };

  const handleEndDateChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newEndDate = event.target.value;
    setEndDate(newEndDate);

    console.log(`Selected Start Date: ${startDate}`);
    console.log(`New End Date: ${newEndDate}`);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(`Start Date is ${startDate} and End Date is ${endDate}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="date">
        {' '}
        <label>Start Date:</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          // pattern="\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}"
          value={startDate}
          onChange={handleStartDateChange}
          min={startDate}
          onFocus={() => setStartDate(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0])}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="date">
        <label>End Date:</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          value={endDate}
          onChange={handleEndDateChange}
          min={startDate}
        />
      </div>
      <button className="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DateInput;
```